# what is the correct way of form validation in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have just created the form and action is `PagesController@check` and the validation is as follows:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')

<div class = "container">
    {!! Form::open(['action' => 'PagesController@check' , 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

        <div class = "form-group">
            {{ Form::label('country','Country')}}
            {{ Form::text('country','', ['class' => 'form-control' , 'placeholder' => ''])}}
        </div>  

        <div class = "form-group">
            {{ Form::label('age','Age')}}
            {{ Form::number('age','', ['class' => 'form-control' , 'placeholder' => ''])}}
        </div>  

        <div class = "form-group">
            {{ Form::label('marks','Marks')}}
            {{ Form::number('marks','', ['class' => 'form-control' , 'placeholder' => ''])}}
        </div>  

        <div class = "form-group">
            {{ Form::label('description','Description')}}
            {{ Form::textarea('description','', ['class' => 'form-control' , 'placeholder' => ''])}}
        </div>  

        {{ Form::submit('Submit' , ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}

    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
@endsection
```

And the `check()` method in the `PagesController` is like this:

```
    public function check(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'country' => 'required',
            'age' => 'required',
            'marks' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required'

            ]);
        return 123;

   }
```

Why is it then it is throwing the following error:

> (2/2) ErrorException
>   Action App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@check not defined. (View: C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\htdocs\website\resources\views\profiles.blade.php)

Here is the whole `PagesController` controller:

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function home() {
        return view('welcome');
    }

    public function about() {
        $title = 'This is the about page';
        return view('about')->with('title',$title);
    }

    public function show() {
        $yomads = person::all();
        return view('show')->with('yomads',$yomads);
    }

    public function profiles(){
       return view('profiles');
    }

    public function check(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'country' => 'required',
            'age' => 'required',
            'marks' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required'

            ]);
        return 123;

   }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your whole PagesController?

Comment: i have added the whole pagescontroller

Comment: what namespace is it under? Everything looks good, only thing I can think of is that the namespace is wrong

Comment: As @Ian says, everything looks good. Maybe try running `composer dump-autoload` in case the file’s cached somehow.

Comment: have you added the route entry in `routes/web.php` ?

Comment: the namespace is :
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\person;

Comment: yes, please tell me what needs to be entered in the routes/web.php ?

Comment: This should be there in your `routes/web.php` file:  `Route::post('any_route_name_here', 'PagesController@check');`

Answer (score 1):

The error most likely has to do with the route (or lack of it) in `app/Http/routes.php` - check that it is properly defined there.

Furthermore, it is good practice to create custom request classes. Have a look at [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation)

These can be generated with artisan:

```
php artisan make:request Profile
```

Then use it, as you were using the standard request:

```
public function check(ProfileRequest $request) {
[...]
```